# EditText AutoCorrect and AutoComplete not working

Tags: android

This is the editText I've defined in the layout XML:

```
    <EditText android:id="@+id/msg_text_input"
    android:text="" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/msg_button_send" 
    android:imeOptions="actionNone"
    android:inputType="text|textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect|textShortMessage"/>
```

However, no autocomplete and no autocorrect takes place after I click the EditText and start typing. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was experimenting and made the following change to the layout XML:

```
    <EditText android:id="@+id/msg_text_input"
    android:text="" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/msg_button_send" 
    android:imeOptions="actionNone"
    android:autoText="true"/>
```

again, on the emulator it does nothing new - BUUUUT - on an actual device the autocorrect shows up !!

Moral of the story is: try it on a device because the emulator is .... not so good

Comment: This doesn't work for me... And the popup in eclipse says that autoText is deprecated.

Comment: I suppose you're compiling against a newer Android - it looks like one should now use `inputType` instead. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#autoText

Answer (score 10):

I was having some problems with auto-correction and it seems that textAutoComplete means that the input will be automatically completed using an array of possible values provided by the application. So it is not the built in dictionary of android, but for example you can provide a list of countries and the user can input the first few letters while the text will be automatically completed by matching items of the list.

Try using textAutoCorrect alone, and the built in android dictionary suggests possible words, corrects spelling mistakes etc... At least it is working for me...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the AutocompleteTextView? http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

Comment: I have wondered about it - and searched through examples - but all the examples show passing in a custom dictionary. I don't want to pass in a dictionary. I want the app to use the dictionary that's already on the phone.

Comment: @someone What dictionary are you trying to use? Maybe you can get the dictionary you are trying to use and dynamically create the resource you need for the AutocompleteTextView (above)?

Comment: whatever dictionary Google uses in their "Messages" app, or the Facebook app uses.

Comment: surely you can just fire an activity to the dictionary to parse the array used by autocomplete?

Comment: I am also looking in to how to use AutocompleteTextView with both my own drop down containing none spelling text together with still getting spelling suggestions above the android keyboard but can not find a solution for this either, had any luck @locoboy?